# Reference on RNiV (Risk not in VaR) estimation

Tags: value-at-risk

I am looking for some good materials to understand the calculation methodologies, regulatory requirements etc. on `RNiV`.

I am particularly interested on following scenario:

Let say we have some instrument for which we need to estimate `VaR`. Say, it has risk factor `X`. In the construction of the time series for that risk factor, part of that directly constructed from `X`, and part of that series comes from some other variable (close) `Y`.

Based on that time series, we estimate `VaR`.

Should the **basis risk** between `X` and `Y` be termed as `RNiV`? What is the guidance from Regulators?

Really appreciate, if you can share some light on above case.

Comment: If you're already calculating ES, rather than VaR, then it's no longer "RIN**V**", but rather NMRF. https://www.risk.net/definition/non-modellable-risk-factors-nmrfs

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks for pointing this out. To bring clarity, I changed the metric to `VaR` in my post, but basic premise of my question remains

Comment: I googled and found https://www.pwc.in/assets/pdfs/consulting/financial-risk-and-regulations/risks-not-in-var-rniv-and-their-role-in-market-risk-management.pdf which cites some FCA guidance on RNIV. Also https://www.icmagroup.org/assets/documents/Regulatory/Secondary-markets/ICMA-SMPC-Epperlein-200218.pdf

Comment: @DimitriVulis Many thanks for these articles. It looks like they suggest recording `RNiV` for such basis/illiquidity risks. May I know as experienced Banker, what is your opinion?

Comment: Let us make up a concrete example. Imagine an emerging market where the only observable are treasury yields and spot FX - think Paraguay or Bolivia, where no one trades IR swaps or FX forwards ever. Suppose you've decided to be a pioneer and hedge a zero-coupon government bond with an FX forward with the same maturity. You intend to hold these to their maturity, but you still have to mark to market the forward somehow to a fair value, and deal with a slew of regulatory guidance / best industry practices that varies by  jurisdiction - RNIV/NMRF, prudent (in addition to fair) valuation,

Comment: independent price/rate verification - rather challending in our example, P&L Explanation, that are all meant to work together to show you both where the daily fair value P&L comes from, and what you might get if you're forced to unwind under "fire sale" conditions. **if** the book is subject to UK RNIV requirements, and if I were tasked with minimizing the capital requirements, then I wouldn't look at RINV in isolation - for sure, I'd decompose the local currency IR into the observable/modelable treasury yield as you describe but then rather than 1 basis, I'd try to proxy...

Comment: the basis between the treasury yield and the onshore swap rate, and the cross-currency basis  from other markets where these are observable. Then we'd be left with a smaller residual/idiosyncratic basis that we might have to feed into the RNIV calculation.  Under FRTB, these proxied bases might or might not be NMRFs - remains to be seen.